# When resubmitting the revised manuscript, what if response to reviewers missed?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I misunderstood the way of submitting response to reviewers document, so I submitted the revised manuscript before uploading response to reviewers. I contacted the journal with the attachment of response to reviewers, and I am worried about what should do next.
Will this resubmission be canceled and be considered as a new submission?

Comment: Is there online system to upload revised version? If yes, and if you are not so late (not more than a week), you should contact the editor and explain details to resubmit the updated version

Comment: "I contacted to journal with the attachment of response to reviewer," I think you did what you could do. Now hope that the processes at the journal work well so that everybody who needs the responses gets them.

Answer (score 2):

Odds are the journal's editors can edit the submission and add the response to reviewers. If this doesn't happen, then chances are the editorial board are very hands-on (or the publisher is very hands-off), but they don't know how to operate the editorial management system. If that happens, write to the publisher and ask them what to do, and the publisher should upload the response to reviewers for you.